# What happens if you await in a thread that isn't in the thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await, threadpool

If I create a new thread like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(.....);
thread.Start(......);
```

What happens if a method inside that thread uses the `await` operator?
I understand that in a normal scenario this would cause .Net to save the state of the current execution and give the thread back to the thread pool so it can work on something else while we wait for the awaited method to complete, but what if this is not in a thread pool thread to begin with?

Comment: It will be the same as when you do this within a console application - because in both situations there is no synchronization context

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? Because you shouldn't do this anyway. Either you are using the async pattern or you're using threads, but don't mix them.

Comment: So if I need to run some code that is async, I should block on it using .Wait()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that in a normal scenario this would cause .Net to save the state of the current execution and give the thread back to the thread pool so it can work on something else while we wait for the awaited method to complete, but what if this is not in a thread pool thread to begin with?

To [clarify a bit](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), `await` will save the local state and then *return*. It doesn't give up the thread right away.

So, in this case, if the `Thread`'s main method returns, then that thread exits. It isn't returned to the thread pool since it's not a thread pool thread; it just exits because its thread proc returned.

There are other scenarios, too:

- If the thread is a UI thread, then it returns to its message loop. The thread keeps running, processing other messages.
- If the thread is the main thread of a Console application, then it exits, which causes the Console app to exit.

> What happens if a method inside that thread uses the await operator?

The same as any other time `await` is used:

- `await` captures the "context" (`SynchronizationContext.Current` or `TaskScheduler.Current`). In this case, the context would be the thread pool context.
- When the method is ready to resume, it resumes on that context.

So in this case, the `await` will return, causing the thread to exit. Then later, the rest of the method will run on a thread pool thread.

Comment: I have some third party libraries used inside my thread method. For example perhaps I want to do an http request. Those methods are all async, so I can use .Wait() to make sure I block the current thread while the I/O happens and therefore keep my thread alive right? What if the underlying code in these libraries uses async await. How can I ensure my thread stays open and doesn't exit and throw more work at the thread pool?

Comment: @Josh: Why do you want these all on a specific thread?

Comment: I have a background task in a web app. It needs to do a range of things. I've had people say that this shouldn't be done on a background task, but regardless, the question above still will bother me regardless of which direction I take!

Comment: @Josh: Blocking on asynchronous code will block your thread, but it will also use the thread pool to run any continuations that your thread is waiting for. So instead of 0-1 threads, it will use 1-2 threads - usually not a good idea. An alternative is to [provide your own `SynchronizationContext` tied to your thread](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) so that `await` will schedule its continuations (by default) to your own thread. But nothing can stop code from using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which means it will resume on a thread pool thread anyway.

Comment: Does this mean I should just let the thread pool run my background task since its longest wait times will be on I/O stuff?

Comment: @Josh: I don't see a need for a separate thread at all; just let the thread pool do the work.

Answer (score 1):

If you "create" the thread, you "manage" it.

Once the code scheduled to run on that thread finishes, the thread will be destroyed.

If you're running async/await code on a thread you crated, chances are that you will run out of that thread soon and pay the price of creating and destroying the thread for no benefit.

Thread pools are used to schedule short lived code and, with async/await that is the norm.

If you have some long running code that blocks, then it might be better to create your own thread.